# koalas groupby -> apply returns 'cannot insert "key", already exists'

Tags: python, pandas, databricks, spark-koalas

I've been struggling with this issue and haven't been able to solve it, I got the current dataframe:

```py
import databricks.koalas as ks

x = ks.DataFrame.from_records(
{'ds': {0: Timestamp('2018-10-06 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2017-06-08 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2018-10-22 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2017-02-08 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2019-02-03 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2019-02-26 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2017-04-15 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2017-07-02 00:00:00'),
  8: Timestamp('2017-04-04 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2017-03-20 00:00:00'),
  10: Timestamp('2018-06-09 00:00:00'),
  11: Timestamp('2017-01-15 00:00:00'),
  12: Timestamp('2018-05-07 00:00:00'),
  13: Timestamp('2018-01-17 00:00:00'),
  14: Timestamp('2017-07-11 00:00:00'),
  15: Timestamp('2018-12-17 00:00:00'),
  16: Timestamp('2018-12-05 00:00:00'),
  17: Timestamp('2017-05-22 00:00:00'),
  18: Timestamp('2017-08-13 00:00:00'),
  19: Timestamp('2018-05-21 00:00:00')},
 'store': {0: 81,
  1: 128,
  2: 81,
  3: 128,
  4: 25,
  5: 128,
  6: 11,
  7: 124,
  8: 43,
  9: 25,
  10: 25,
  11: 124,
  12: 124,
  13: 128,
  14: 81,
  15: 11,
  16: 124,
  17: 11,
  18: 167,
  19: 128},
 'stock': {0: 1,
  1: 236,
  2: 3,
  3: 9,
  4: 36,
  5: 78,
  6: 146,
  7: 20,
  8: 12,
  9: 12,
  10: 15,
  11: 25,
  12: 10,
  13: 7,
  14: 0,
  15: 230,
  16: 80,
  17: 6,
  18: 110,
  19: 8},
 'sells': {0: 1.0,
  1: 17.0,
  2: 1.0,
  3: 2.0,
  4: 1.0,
  5: 2.0,
  6: 7.0,
  7: 1.0,
  8: 1.0,
  9: 1.0,
  10: 2.0,
  11: 1.0,
  12: 1.0,
  13: 1.0,
  14: 1.0,
  15: 1.0,
  16: 1.0,
  17: 3.0,
  18: 2.0,
  19: 1.0}}
)
```

and this function that I want to use in a groupby - apply:

```py
import numpy as np

def compute_indicator(df):
  return (
    df.copy()
    .assign(
      indicator=lambda x: x['a'] < np.percentile(x['b'], 80)
    )
    .astype(int)
    .fillna(1)
  )
```

Where df is meant to be a pandas DataFrame. If I do a group-by apply using pandas, the code executes as expected:

```
import pandas as pd
# This runs
a = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x.to_dict()).groupby('store').apply(compute_indicator)
```

but when trying to run the same on koalas it gives me the following error: `ValueError: cannot insert store, already exists`

```
x.groupby('store').apply(compute_indicator)
# ValueError: cannot insert store, already exists
```

I cannot use the typing annotation in `compute_indicator` because some columns are not fixed (they travel around with the dataframe, meant to be used by another transformations).

What should I do to run the code in koalas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for Koalas 0.29.0, when `koalas.DataFrame.groupby(keys).apply(f)` runs for the first time over an untyped func `f`, it has to infer the schema, and to do this runs `pandas.DataFrame.head(n).groupby(keys).apply(f)`. The probem is that pandas `apply` receives as argument the dataframe with the groupby keys as index and as columns (see this [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32384)).

The result of `pandas.DataFrame.head(h).groupby(keys).apply(f)` is then converted to a `koalas.DataFrame`, so if `f` doesn't drop the `keys` columns this conversion raises an exception because of duplicated column names (see [issue](https://github.com/databricks/koalas/issues/1361))